# How harmful is a wide Dense layer after a narrow?

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, information-theory, autoencoders, residual-networks

My CNN-LSTM EEG Keras classification model includes a Dense 'shortcut' connection for residual sequence learning as shown below; to match dimensionality, the Dense layer's set to `2*lstm_dim`. When feeding very long sequences (>200,000 timesteps), this Dense layer dominates model size (# of weights) - making it x10+ as large. To mitigate, I figured two approaches:

- **(1)** Downsampling CNN output via bigger MaxPooling; *downside*: lowers effectiveness of stacked Bi-LSTMs, first of which has `return_sequences=True`. Downsampling for Dense alone would create an information flow disparity
- **(2)** Inserting a narrower layer (e.g. `lstm_dim/2`) before the `2*lstm_dim` layer; *downside*: *(a)* applies additional non-linearity to transformed features, possibly hampering residual learning

*(b)* The narrow layer may *bottleneck* the flow of information, with the wide layer *oversampling* the former and complicating learning - as with Autoencoders.

All considered, is a wider subsequent Dense layer unadvisable? Given the already-extensive hyperparameter space for my model, existing research / insight on the matter is appreciated.

---

[image]

Comment: Did you find out answer to your question ?

Comment: @DanielWiczew I'd say in general, it's a bad idea: we first bottleneck information then expect its recovery in an even more useful form. This can happen in only specific architectural settings, and with enough data.

Comment: I did a quick research yesterday and it's not always the case:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.00094.pdf
In general wider layer after smaller layer is sometimes preferable. Try to play with https://playground.tensorflow.org/ and put 2:8:2 architecture.